# Bind event to specific elements

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to bind the mouse-down event to the body and all it's children, except some items, using angular.

My code is:

```
angular.element('body *').not('.searchContainer, .searchContainer *, 
                              #globalSearchInput, #globalSearchTypeMoreOptions,
                              #globalSearchTypeMoreOptions *').bind('mousedown', 
                              function(e){
                                    scope.targetElement = angular.element(e.target);
                              });
```

But, it binds the event to the items in not too.

I've tried with jQuery too, but still attaching the event the not selector.

Comment: This is an extremely unperformant selector and attaching a mouse down to all those elements is unneeded since the event bubbles. Perhaps if you describe why you are trying to do this we could help give you a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm misreading your post, but it seems like you are open to using jquery instead of angular js.

Using jquery, you could bind to the `$('body').mouseup();` event and just stop the event propagation if the target element is one of the "exceptions":

```js
// create an object to contain your "exception" elements (pink ones)
var notMeElems = $('#globalSearchInput, .searchContainer');


// bind to the bodey mouseup event
$('body').mousedown(function (e) {
  
    // if the target element is part of your exclusion object...
    if ($(e.target).is(notMeElems)) {
      
      // stop the event propogation
        return false;
    }
  
    // or do something else
    $(this).toggleClass('black');
  
});
```

```css
div {
    padding: 20px;
    border: dashed 2px steelblue;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.searchContainer, #globalSearchInput {
    background-color: pink;
}
.black{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="globalSearchInput">#globalSearchInput</div>
<div id="div2" class="searchContainer"> Search Container</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
<div id="div5" class="searchContainer">Search Container</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clear what you are trying to achieve, I think this is what you need.

Use the angular `ng-mousedown` property on the body, like this:

```
<body ng-mousedown="mousedownFunc()">
```

Then utilize the `$event.stopPropagation()` function on the elements you want excluded, like this:

```
<div class="searchContainer" ng-mousedown="$event.stopPropagation()">
   ...
</div>
```

Created simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovjgu4wz/) to illustrate it